# SharePoint Online - Modern List View Web Part forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view, modern-experience, communication-site

I have a modern list and I want to surface it on a communication site using the modern list view web part. All is fine until I click one of the items on that list. It redirects me into a full screen view with the details of that list item on the upper left corner.

I would like for the list view web part to open the items into the side panel just like in the modern list itself.

So to sum it up, I would like to know how to get the list view web part forms open up in the "dialog" or side panel the same way they do in the list page. Can this be done? Are there any tricks to accomplish this?

NOTE: I have tried going into the list settings and enabling the "Open in dialog" -thing. Didn't do anything.

I'm grateful for any help regarding this matter!

Kind regards,
Tenttu

Comment: I have got the same question like you. Did you anyhow solve your issue ? Thanks in advance,
Sonja

Comment: @HasSo Unfortunately not, some time ago I asked about it from O365 support and they said it can't be done at the moment. The side panel works in lists themselves but not in the list webpart. If you find a solution, please share it here! I will also write an update if I manage to find any solutions to this. :)